# react-native-router-flux and replacing root controller

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to create a simple app for a blog. The blog has multiple categories, where each category has its own stories.

My architecture is supposed to be pretty simple: a root controller which should display a list of stories, and on top I'll push each story. The app has a drawer where a user can switch a category (which is where it starts to be messy - since at that point, I don't want to push the new list but to replace the root with the new category).

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {return (
        <Drawer>
            <Router sceneStyle={{paddingTop: Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.General.TotalNavHeight}}>
                <Scene key='root'>
                    <Scene
                        key='category'
                        component={Category}
                        type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
                        title='Main'
                        passProps={true}
                        category='main'
                    />
                    <Scene key='story' component={Story} />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        </Drawer>
    )}
}
```

When a user is trying to switch a category, I'm calling:

```
Actions.category({title: data.title, category: data.category});
```

And when the user clicks on a story in the list, I do:

```
Actions.story({title: data.title, category: this.props.category, story: data.story});
```

When switching a category, I would like to pop all existing controllers and replace the root one, but it doesn't work for me right now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`Actions.category({ type: 'reset' , ...otherProps})` ??

Comment: it should .. https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#scene does it work if you dont pass the otherProps ?

Comment: I call `Actions.category({ type: 'reset' })` in my code and it works for me.

Comment: maybe strip back the route a bit, see if anything there is causing an issue?